# Heapsort algorithm CLRS

Tags: c, algorithm, heapsort, clrs

I was implementing a heapsort algorithm in C according to CLRS. However I am unable to get a sorted output. Can you please have a look and tell what is wrong with my code. Functions `maxheap` and `buildmaxheap` works. I am not able to figure what is wrong with the code.

The code is supposed to heapsort the array elements. I feel there is an error in the `heapsort()` function as the `maxheap` and `buildmaxheap` work just fine.

The final output I am getting is

```
1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1
```

But the expected output should be

```
1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10 14 16
```

The code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define maxn 11
int n=10;

int parent(int i)
{
    return i/2;
}

int left(int i)
{
    return 2*i+0;
}

int right(int i)
{
    return 2*i+1+0;
}

void  max_heap(int x[],int i,int heapsize)
{
    int largest;
    int l=left(i);
    int r=right(i);

    if (l<=heapsize &&  x[l]>x[i]){
        largest=l;
    }
    else
    {
        largest=i;
    }
    if (r<=heapsize && x[r]>x[largest]){
        largest=r;
    }
    if (largest!=i)
    {
        int s=x[i];x[i]=x[largest];x[largest]=s;
        max_heap(x,largest,heapsize);
    }
}

void buildmaxheap(int x[],int heapsize)
{

    int i;
    for(i=5;i>=1;i--)
        max_heap(x,i,heapsize);

}

void heapsort(int x[])
{
    buildmaxheap(x,10);
    int i,t,heapsize=10;
    for(i=10;i>=2;i--)
    {
        int s=x[i];x[1]=x[i];x[i]=s;

        heapsize--;
        /*
         printf("%d",heapsize);
         */
        max_heap(x,i,heapsize);
    }
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
        printf("%d\t",x[i]);

}

int main()
{
    int x[maxn],i;
    x[1]=16;
    x[2]=4;
    x[3]=10;
    x[4]=14;
    x[5]=7;
    x[6]=9;
    x[7]=3;
    x[8]=2;
    x[9]=8;
    x[10]=1;
    heapsort(x);
    /*
     for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
     printf("%d\t",x[i]);
     */
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well, it wastes x[0]. to start with.  I don't trust C arrays with '1..' indexing, even if declared oversized to start with:(

Comment: The heapsort function. This is the output I am getting after printing the array after heapsort function: 
1       1       1       1       2       1       2       2       1       1

Comment: 1. Use a debugger. 2. Arrays in C are zero-based, not one-based. Don't run from that fact; embrace it. 3. An element at index `i` in an array with the heap property *potentially* has children at slots `2*i+1` and `2*(i+1)`, restricted by the overall sequence length `N` (meaning if either of those compute to values equal or greater to `N`, that child does not exist).

Comment: You need to add more details to the quesion, or it will be closed as off topic: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Comment: Just a point: although you have `#define maxn 11` and `int n=10;` you've (almost) ignored them and hard coded using `5` and `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lack of logic in heapsort. Any sort algorithm has to compare 2 values and do one thing for less than, another for greater and leave well alone if the same. At present you automatically swap a comparator with index 1 multiple times.

I can't clearly see why it's loosing numbers resulting in random 1's and 2's, but it looks so broken that I'm not giving anymore time until you try again.

In c the array index begin from 0, don't avoid it in this little 10 node quandary it's nothing much. But if you don't start to automatically consider zero to be first you will pay big time.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
int s=x[i];x[1]=x[i];x[i]=s;
```

looks like it's trying to do a swap, but it's mixed up. Look at the indexes and think about the order.

After you fix that, there's still another bug. I don't have the book so I don't know exactly what it told you to do, but I believe you need to fix up the heap property starting *from the root* after you remove an element, and your code doesn't do that.